# Accidentally chose wrong login manger during upgrade

Tags: 12.10, login, gdm

I ended up choosing gdm as my login manager during my upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. Now all I have is the boring default gray gdm login. How can I change it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and make `lightdm` your default display manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Use arrow keys (<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the menu that appear in terminal to select `lightdm` as default.

Then go in tty1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run next two commands:

```
sudo service stop gdm
sudo service start lightdm
```

Comment: You're very wise, thank you for your answer. It's now fixed!

Comment: @Eli I edited my answer to make the changes permanently.